# Make a Rails page load with a Bootstrap modal visible after failed form submission

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, ruby-on-rails-4.2

I have an "index" view that lists all my things. To add a new thing I have a button that activates a modal with a form (so there's no "new" view). The form has a password field and if you give the wrong password, I want it to render the index view (cause remember, there's no "new" view) but with the modal still visible so they can try again. How do I tell the page to load with the modal still visible

```
  def create
    @thing = Thing.new(thing_params)
    if params[:thing][:secret] == "Secret"
      if @thing.save
        flash[:notice] = "'#{@thing.name}' saved!"
        redirect_to things_path
      else
        flash[:notice] = "Something went wrong :("
        render "index"
      end
    else
      flash[:notice] = "Incorrect secret word."
      @things = Thing.all
      render "index"

      # BUT RENDER IT WITH THE MODAL STILL OPEN!!

    end
  end
```

If I need to restructure the way I'm doing this (like if I actually should have a "new" view), feel free to tell me.

Comment: Would playing wuth the submit button enability according to your validation be better for you ?  It solves the probleme on one hand for sure, and its more modern on the other . Just a suggestion :)

Comment: @IKENLemjahedAyoub I'm not sure I know what you mean by that. Can you elaborate?

Comment: If all the inputs are valid ( email format, password length, etc ) then you enable the submit button ( make it clickable there a class in bootstrap for that , 'disabled' Iguess ), if only one field is invalid then the submit button never get clickable, technically remove the class 'disabled' from the submit button tag, its easy to do wuth js.

Comment: @IKENLemjahedAyoub I like that idea. I'll play with it.

Comment: Glad to help enlightening a potential solution for you. Good luck

Comment: did it go well @wetjosh ?

Comment: @IKENLemjahedAyoub I got it working using on keyup. Basically I check the "secret" field every button press to see if it matches the secret word and if it does, I remove the 'disabled' class and the disabled='disabled' attribute on the submit button. I don't feel great about the implementation (I'm storing the "secret" locally in the javascript rather than server-side), but it gets the job done. Security is not important really at all. Just trying to avoid accidents. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: I see, but i like it though, thanks for the update. Keep it up. Cheers :D